# Importing Data with read_csv into DF

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have tried to import csv via pandas. But `df.head` shows the data in wrong rows (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siFtW.png)).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Dokumenty\ML\winequality-red.csv")
df.head()
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your data is not 'comma' seperated but 'semicolon' separated. Try adding this separator parameter.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Dokumenty\ML\winequality-red.csv", sep=';')
```

Comment: @Tekier did it work?